# Angular on Electron - using Observable to update UI

Tags: angular, asynchronous, electron, observable, ngfor

I am trying to develop a desktop app using Electron with Angular in front-end. It utilizes Node mssql package in back-end to query a database, and should present retrieved data in somewhat desktop-looking UI - for the sake of this topic, let's say it is going to be visualised in table.

For now, until i will figure it out, the app presents like this:

Has text input to provide direct sql query, button to send it , and table to iterate through resultset.

**Component's template:**

```
 <input type="text" id="queryInput" margin="5,5,5,5" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="queryTerm" />
  <button class="button btn-info" (click)="onQuery()" margin="5,5,5,5">
    Execute
  </button>
  <table id="dataTable" margin="5,5,5,5" class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let item of shipments | async">
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.WMSObjectId}}</td>
      <td>{{item.ShipNr}}</td>
      <td>{{item.SupplyLetterNr}}</td>
      <td>{{item.ArrivPeriodStartDT}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Here is the component class:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Curiosity';
  placeholder: string = 'Type query in here';
  queryTerm: string = "";
  queryResult: IShipment[] = [];
  shipments: Observable<IShipment[]> | undefined;

  constructor(private _sqlClientService: SQLClientService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shipments = new Observable<IShipment[]>((observer: Observer<IShipment[]>) => {
      observer.next(this.getQueryResults());
    });
  }

  onQuery(): void {
    this._sqlClientService.sqlQuery(this.queryTerm, (response: IResponseObject) => this.updateResultSet(response));
  }

  updateResultSet(response : IResponseObject) : void{
    this.queryResult = response.recordset;
    console.log(this.queryResult);
  }

  getQueryResults() : IShipment[]{
    return this.queryResult;
  }

}
```

The problem that im struggling to overcome is to let the UI know, that there is data to present, so *ngFor could populate the table.

I can see that data retrieval is completed, because updateResultSet is showing it in the console, but i don't quite understand how to push it to UI.

How exactly do i trigger next()?

Once i used `setInterval(() => observer.next(this.getQueryResults()),1000);` just to test it, and THEN it works, but that's not a correct way ofcourse.

Comment: May I ask why do you render multiple tables with a single row, instead of rendering a single table with multiple rows? You might want to move the `ngFor` on the `tr` instead...

Comment: Thanks, i am new to angular - i'm going to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor and use it, would this help?

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

```
  constructor(private _sqlClientService: SQLClientService, private _changeDetectorRef ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  updateResultSet(response: IResponseObject): void {
    this.queryResult.next(response.recordset);
    _changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.queryResult);
  }
```

Comment: In combination with Octavian's solution it works perfectly

Comment: But this is quite dirty solution. U don't need BehaviorSubject at all when using `_changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` Anybody managed to make it work - to detect changes automaticly by Angular without explicitly calling changeDetector?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `BehaviorSubject` to accomplish the desired behavior. It would be best to put it in a separate service and expose it `asObservable` instead of managing it in the component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Curiosity';
  placeholder: string = 'Type query in here';
  queryTerm: string = '';
  queryResult = new BehaviorSubject<IShipment[]>([]);

  constructor(private _sqlClientService: SQLClientService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onQuery(): void {
    this._sqlClientService.sqlQuery(
      this.queryTerm,
      (response: IResponseObject) => this.updateResultSet(response)
    );
  }

  updateResultSet(response: IResponseObject): void {
    this.queryResult.next(response.recordset);
    console.log(this.queryResult);
  }
}
```

And the relevant part of the template:

```html
<table id="dataTable" margin="5,5,5,5" class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let item of queryResult | async">
```

Comment: It actually does work, but not on the first click - i am getting only console.log at first one.

Comment: What's in the log? You should put the `response` in the log instead, not the `queryResult`.

Comment: I deliberately put `queryResult` in the log, to see if it gets data properly - it does. With your solution, it's an object with `_value: Array(`here i can see ma dataset`) .